# How to sum number of hours with date

Tags: r

I have a large dataset over a long time with multiple individuals that looks like this

```
event.id   timestamp             individual 
1          2021-08-31 09:03:01   A  
2          2021-08-31 10:02:11   A
3          2021-08-31 11:02:20   A
4          2021-08-31 12:02:20   A
5          2021-08-29 09:38:21   B
6          2021-08-29 09:53:06   B
7          2021-08-29 10:08:06   B
```

I want to calculate the sum of the number of hours of the records per individual (e.g., if individual A has less than 5hours of data, I would remove it). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(hrs = difftime(max(timestamp), min(timestamp), unit = "hours") |> 
  filter(hrs >= 5, .by = individual)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base R`approach

```
# (1)
df$timestamp <- strptime(df$timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
# (2)
new_df <- aggregate(x = list(time_difference = df$timestamp), 
                    by = list(indiviudal = df$individual), 
                    FUN = \(i) difftime(max(i), min(i), unit = "hours"))
# (3)
new_df[new_df$time_difference >= 5L, ]
```

Convert `timestamp` to class `POSIXlt` if its not already done (#1). Use `aggregate()` to calculate time differences in hours per individual (#2).
Finally, subset `new_df` which results in an empty data frame per your toy data (#3).